# spring integration tcp client send simple message

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-integration-ip

I've been developing a project using spring framework 4. I'm trying to create a simple TCP client via `spring-integration-ip` library. I've adjusted all configurations:

### applicationContext.xml

```
...
<int:channel id="tcpChannel" />

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-channel-adapter id="outboundClient"
channel="tcpChannel"
connection-factory="tcpConnectionFactory"/>

...
```

### bean configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration{

   @Bean
   public AbstractClientConnectionFactory tcpConnectionFactory() { 
       return new TcpNetClientConnectionFactory("localhost", 2345);
   }
}
```

I've read all documentations about spring tcp [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html).
I guess I must use  `tcp-outbound-channel-adapter` or `gateway` to send messages. but I wonder how to use it; what method should I invoke. I'm not supposed to receive any messages from server.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. I didn't need `gateway`. spring messaging `gateway`s have been designed to implement the request-response scenario. So the only thing I need to do is that I send message vi `channel`. Perhaps there be some better solutions.

```
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

public class MyOwnService{

   @Inject
   private MessageChannel channel;

   public void someMethod(String message){
      Message<String> m = MessageBuilder.withPayload(message).build();
      channel.send(m);
   }
}
```